# USB Host controller: xhci-hcd Event TRB with no TDs queued spam during audio playback

Tags: linux, drivers, usb, usb-audio

I'm on a system with Linux Kernel v5.10.4, and facing an issue where during audio playback through ALSA (aplay). The kernel spams the following log for the duration of the playback and no audio is heard:

```
xhci-hcd f2500000.usb3: WARN Event TRB for slot 3 ep 1 with no TDs queued?
xhci-hcd f2500000.usb3: WARN Event TRB for slot 3 ep 1 with no TDs queued?
xhci-hcd f2500000.usb3: WARN Event TRB for slot 3 ep 1 with no TDs queued?
...
```

- I've tried resetting (power off/on) the USB audio card, but the xhci-hcd is in the same error state.
- The issue resolves if I reset the USB hub.
- The issue resolves if I reboot the system.
- I'm able to reproduce the issue by doing `speaker-test` for more than 4 periods. The issue doesn't occur with shorter periods.

---

I do not know how to troubleshoot whether this is a driver issue or a hardware issue.

- Do I need a xhci driver update to fix the issue?
- Any mitigation to restart / recover the driver (without rebooting or resetting the entire USB hub)?

---

[Warn log in source driver v5.10.4](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/09162bc32c880a791c6c0668ce0745cf7958f576/drivers/usb/host/xhci-ring.c#L2558-L2560)

`snd-usb-audio` is present in the kernel.

Found a related [post](http://billauer.co.il/blog/2019/11/xhci-controller-bug-warning/) but the mentioned fix was done in kernel v4.15

Comment: I think this is happening because `speaker-test` is writing a way bigger of buffer. With smaller (or card compatible rate, buffer), the issue is not reproduced. Ex. speaker-test -P 4 -l 4 -r 48000 -b 24000 -p 6000.

However, the original issue cripples the driver (audio playback) and puts it in a bad state which does not recover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried changing the sample rate of the file you're playing?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. 

Tried this. The issue seems to be occurring with 48 kHz sample rate wav files, but seems to be not occurring with 8 kHz / 44.1 kHz sample rate. The audio codec supports 8 kHz to 48 kHz, but 48 kHz seems to be causing this. 

As I alluded in the original thread, this seems to be related to the card's supported rate, or the buffer sizes.